# Effect of Number of States in a Hidden Markov Model based classifier

Tags: machine-learning, probability, hidden-markov-models

What is the relation between the **number of clusters/codebook**, **number of states** in a **hidden markov model**

**How do number of states affect the performance of hidden markov model based classifier?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally , If the number of states are not very large, the accuracy will increase with the increase of the number hidden state in classification. If the number of states are large, the accuracy will not increase any more. And the increase of the number of hidden states will lead to more computation.

Answer (score 0):

Let **N** be the number of states and **T** be the length of your state and observation sequences:

If you want to calculate P(Observations(up to t), State(t)=S| Model) directly, it requires on the order of 2*T*(N^T) calculations. It is therefore a bad idea to try and calculate this probability directly.

If, instead, you wish to use the forward-backward algorithm, it requires on the order of (N^2)*T calculations, substantially faster than the direct approach.

So, for 2 states and 10 time points, you would need to make (2^2)*10= 40 computations to obtain P(Observations(up to t), State(t)=S| Model) with the forward-backward algorithm.

```
# States    # Calculations
   2  ->        40
   3  ->        90
   4  ->        160
   5  ->        250
   ...
```